# use JDBC at GoogleAppsScript. don't connect myDB(mysql)

Tags: mysql, google-apps-script, jdbc

I want to connect mysql from GoogleAppsScript.
but could not connect.
I use `Centos7`
I stopped fireWall

i write googleAppsScript for

```
var conn = Jdbc.getConnection('jdbc:mysql:ServerIP:3306/DBName','DBUser','DBPassword');
```

error(A database connection could not be established. Check the connection string, user name, and password.)

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/jdbc#getConnection(String,String,String)

Comment: Your JDBC URL is incorrect for MySQL, the correct URL would be of the form `jdbc:mysql://ServerIP:3306/DBName`

Comment: thank you!
I change Code.
but no good.

It may be a server side problem..